# Convergence in Probability - Hitting the Limit

Tags: probability-theory, coupling

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_\infty$ be discrete random variables taking values in a finite or countable set $E$. Suppose that for each $x\in E$, $$\mathbf{P}\left(X_n = x\right) \to \mathbf{P}\left(X_\infty = x\right)$$ as $n \to \infty$.

It can be shown [Sections 6.1-6.2 of *Coupling, Stationarity, and Regeneration (Probability and Its Applications)* by Hermann Thorisson] that this implies the existence of a coupling $\left(X_{1}',X_{2}',\ldots, X_{\infty}'\right)$ of $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_\infty$ and a finite random integer $K$ such that $$n\ge K \implies X_n'=X_\infty'.$$

> Since $X_n'$ has the same distribution as $X_n$, and $X_\infty '$ has the same distribution as $X_\infty '$, wouldn't the equation $X_n'=X_\infty'$ imply that $X_n$ has the same distribution as $X_\infty$? I don't believe so since I can find variables $X_n$ that converge in probability to some limiting distribution $X_\infty$ such that $X_n$ and $X_\infty$ never have the same distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were given $\mathbb P(X_n'=X_\infty') = 1$, that would imply $X_n$ equal to $X_\infty$ in distribution. However, that's not the result you're given. You have $$\mathbb P(X_n'=X_\infty') \ge \mathbb P(K \le n) \to 1$$ as $n \to \infty$, which does not imply equality in distribution for any finite $n$.

Comment: If $n>K$, then $X_{n}' = X_{\infty}'$, which will imply $P(X_{n}' = X_{\infty}'=1$? This doesn't exactly agree with your displayed expression.

Comment: No, it won't. $K$ is random; the event $n > K$ is a random event, with some probability between $0$ and $1$. @TheSubstitute